# How to crawl realtime data with cheerio and socketio

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, sql-server

I'm craw data a website. Can anyone guide me how to get web data if there is a change on the web then use socket to update automatically.
I used cheerio to crawl the data. But I want to apply more socket here so it's realtime.
Thank you very much

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think cheerio cannot handle that event changes. cause these changes are coming from runtime but cheerio only renders once you feed it.

I had this issue before and I solved it with [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer). you can run the web page. after that, you can track everything in runtime. then, you can create observable objects to detect changes inside the DOM.